# How to create conditional bean to be used for only one bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I created a bean on my Configuration class but I want only one bean should use this custom bean. I don't want any other bean can use this.

Here's my Configuration class;

```
@Configuration
public class ProcessorConfig {

    @Bean
    public List<Processor> processors(){
        SSto processor1 = new SSto();
        CSto processor2 = new CSto();
        DGTu processor3 = new DGTu();
        EGam processor4 = new EGam();

        return of(processor1, processor2, processor3, processor4);
    }
}
```

And this is the bean that I want to use this custom bean.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProcessorDecorator {

    private final List<Processor> processors;

    public void apply(Ga ga) {
        this.processors.forEach(processor -> processor.apply(ga));
    }

}
```

I just want this **ProcessorDecorator** class to inject **List processors**. No other class can inject this **List processors**.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only to `ProcessorDecorator` to only have this list of processors why not declare those processors in `ProcessorDecorator` ?

other way would be specifing custom name for bean
`@Bean(name = "decoratorProcessors")`

and adding qualifier in `ProcessorDecorator` `@Qualifier("decoratorProcessors")` but other classes injecting processors should probably have `@Qualifier("processors")` to block them from injecting `decoratorProcessors`